# React hook logging a useState element as null when it is not

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a method,

```
const handleUpvote = (post, index) => {
  let newPosts = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(mappedPosts));

  console.log('mappedPosts', mappedPosts); // null
  console.log('newPosts', newPosts); // null

  if (post.userAction === "like") {
    newPosts.userAction = null;
  } else {
    newPosts.userAction = "like";
  }

  setMappedPosts(newPosts);

  upvote(user.id, post._id);
};
```

That is attached to a mapped element,

```
const mapped = userPosts.map((post, index) => ( 
    <ListItem 
      rightIcon = {
        onPress = {
          () => handleUpvote(post, index)
        }
   ......
```

And I have

```
  const [mappedPosts, setMappedPosts] = useState(null);
```

When the component mounts, it takes `userPosts` from the redux state, maps them out to a `ListItem` and appropriately displays it. The problem is that whenever `handleUpvote()` is entered, it sees `mappedPosts` as null and therefore sets the whole List to null at `setMappedPosts(newPosts);`

What am I doing wrong here? `mappedPosts` is indeed not null at the point when `handleUpvote()` is clicked because.. well how can it be, if a `mappedPosts` element was what invoked the `handleUpvote()` method in the first place?

I tried something like

```
    setMappedPosts({
      ...mappedPosts,
      mappedPosts[index]: post
    });
```

But that doesn't even compile. Not sure where to go from here

---

## Edit

Whole component:

```
const Profile = ({
  navigation,
  posts: { userPosts, loading },
  auth: { user, isAuthenticated },
  fetchMedia,
  checkAuth,
  upvote,
  downvote
}) => {
  const { navigate, replace, popToTop } = navigation;

  const [mappedPosts, setMappedPosts] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (userPosts) {
      userPosts.forEach((post, index) => {
        post.userAction = null;

        post.likes.forEach(like => {
          if (like._id.toString() === user.id) {
            post.userAction = "liked";
          }
        });

        post.dislikes.forEach(dislike => {
          if (dislike._id.toString() === user.id) {
            post.userAction = "disliked";
          }
        });
      });

      const mapped = userPosts.map((post, index) => (
        <ListItem
          Component={TouchableScale}
          friction={100}
          tension={100}
          activeScale={0.95}
          key={index}
          title={post.title}
          bottomDivider={true}
          rightIcon={
            <View>
              <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "center" }}>
                <Icon
                  name="md-arrow-up"
                  type="ionicon"
                  color={post.userAction === "liked" ? "#a45151" : "#517fa4"}
                  onPress={() => handleUpvote(post, index)}
                />
                <View style={{ marginLeft: 10, marginRight: 10 }}>
                  <Text>{post.likes.length - post.dislikes.length}</Text>
                </View>
                <Icon
                  name="md-arrow-down"
                  type="ionicon"
                  color={post.userAction === "disliked" ? "#8751a4" : "#517fa4"}
                  onPress={() => handleDownvote(post, index)}
                />
              </View>
              <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
                <Text>{post.comments.length} comments</Text>
              </View>
            </View>
          }
          leftIcon={
            <View style={{ height: 50, width: 50 }}>
              <ImagePlaceholder
                src={post.image.location}
                placeholder={post.image.location}
                duration={1000}
                showActivityIndicator={true}
                activityIndicatorProps={{
                  size: "large",
                  color: index % 2 === 0 ? "blue" : "red"
                }}
              />
            </View>
          }
        ></ListItem>
      ));

      setMappedPosts(mapped);
    } else {
      checkAuth();
      fetchMedia();
    }
  }, [userPosts, mappedPosts]);

  const handleDownvote = (post, index) => {
    let newPosts = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(mappedPosts));

    if (post.userAction === "dislike") {
      newPosts.userAction = null;
    } else {
      newPosts.userAction = "dislike";
    }

    setMappedPosts(newPosts);

    downvote(user.id, post._id);
  };

  const handleUpvote = post => {
    let newPosts = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(mappedPosts));

    console.log("mappedPosts", mappedPosts); // null
    console.log("newPosts", newPosts); // null

    if (post.userAction === "like") {
      newPosts.userAction = null;
    } else {
      newPosts.userAction = "like";
    }

    setMappedPosts(newPosts);

    upvote(user.id, post._id);
  };

  return mappedPosts === null ? (
    <Spinner />
  ) : (
    <ScrollView
      refreshControl={
        <RefreshControl
          refreshing={false}
          onRefresh={() => {
            this.refreshing = true;
            fetchMedia();
            this.refreshing = false;
          }}
        />
      }
    >
      {mappedPosts}
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  }
});

Profile.propTypes = {
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  posts: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  fetchMedia: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  checkAuth: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  upvote: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  downvote: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth,
  posts: state.posts
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { fetchMedia, checkAuth, upvote, downvote }
)(Profile);
```

Comment: Please provide [MCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Did you try passing `mappedProps` to the function? The original null value is probably captured in the closure.

Comment: I can't pass mappedProps because mappedProps mappedProps is set with `setMappedProps(mapped)`, as `mapped` is in the `useEffect()`

Comment: Can you show the entire component? Your code is missing something that causes this issue.

Comment: @AndrzejZiółek The flow is retrieve data from API > set data to redux state > component gets notified of new data > that components useEffect is invoked > component renders a mapped List with that data. It's not going to be possible to provide an MCE without providing the code of the data flow

Comment: @goto1 Sure, I edited the OP

Comment: @MikeK are you still having issues?

Comment: Nope, thank you, just forgot to mark as answer. It kinda sucks to have to use two useEffects, but I guess that just how it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why your current solution doesn't work is because you're rendering `userPosts` inside of the `useEffect` hook, which looks like it only runs once, ends up "caching" the initial state, and that's what you end up seeing in your handlers.

You will need to use multiple hooks to get this working properly:

```js
const Profile = (props) => {
  // ...
  const [mappedPosts, setMappedPosts] = useState(null)
  const [renderedPosts, setRenderedPosts] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.userPosts) {
      const userPosts = props.userPosts.map(post => {
        post.userAction = null;
        
        // ...
      })      
      setMappedPosts(userPosts)
    } else {
      checkAuth()
      fetchMedia()
    }
  }, [props.userPosts])

  const handleDownvote = (post, index) => {
    // ...
    setMappedPosts(newPosts)
  }
  const handleUpvote = (post) => {
    // ...
    setMappedPosts(newPosts)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!mappedPosts) {
      return
    }
    const renderedPosts = mappedPosts.map((post, index) => {
      return (...)
    })
    setRenderedPosts(renderedPosts)
  }, [mappedPosts])

  return !renderedPosts ? null : (...)
}
```

Here's a simplified example that does what you're trying to do:

- [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-hooks-dc9wu?fontsize=14)

---

Also, one note, **don't do this**:

```js
const Profile = (props) => {
  const [mappedPosts, setMappedPosts] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (userPosts) {
      setMappedPosts() // DON'T DO THIS!
    } else {
      // ...
    }
  }, [userPosts, mappedPosts])
}
```

Stay away from updating a piece of state inside of a hook that has it in its dependency array. You will run into an infinite loop which will cause your component to keep re-rendering until it crashes.

Comment: This is a prime example of why react hooks are a nightmare. This would be child's play with plain JS but react always finds a way of overcomplicating the simplest concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Let me use a simplified example to explain the problem:

```
const Example = props => {
    const { components_raw } = props;
    const [components, setComponents] = useState([]);
    const logComponents = () => console.log(components);

    useEffect(() => {
        // At this point logComponents is equivalent to
        // logComponents = () => console.log([])
        const components_new = components_raw.map(_ => (
            <div onClick={logComponents} />
        ));

        setComponents(components_new);
    }, [components_raw]);

    return components;
};
```

As you can see the cycle in which `setComponents` is called, components is empty `[]`. Once the state is assigned, it stays with the value `logComponents` had, it doesn't matter if it changes in a future cycle.

To solve it you could modify the necessary element from the received data, no components. Then add the onClick on the return in render.

```
const Example = props => {
    const { data_raw } = props;
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const logData = () => console.log(data);

    useEffect(() => {
        const data_new = data_raw.map(data_el => ({
            ...data_el // Any transformation you need to do to the raw data.
        }));

        setData(data_new);
    }, [data_raw]);

    return data.map(data_el => <div {...data_el} onClick={logData} />);
};
```